# Как сделать полное зеркало проекта GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Использую сейчас зеркалирование репозитория. Весьма удобная штука, но не зеркалирует issue и wiki как бы их тоже гонять? В настройках и документации не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, такого функционала не предоставляется. Поэтому требуется небольшие манипуляции. Для начала посмотрите, этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169164/mirror-gitlab-wiki-to-github).

Wiki - это отдельный репозиторий, поэтому его клонируйте так:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/someuser/{project}.wiki.git
```

А вот с issues  смотрите этот [туториал](http://it-nonwhizzos.blogspot.com/2015/11/perl-script-to-backup-gitlabcom-project.html).